# looking for solution, if i dont press any key or touch the screen for 2 minutes on windows-mobile - i need to return to LogIn screen

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

looking for solution, if i dont press any key or touch the screen for 2 minutes on windows-mobile

i need to return to LogIn screen (from any screen of my program).

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Run a timer which resets when you receive a OnTouch or OnKey Event and after a specified time return to to the Login Screen.

```
public partial class AnotherScreen : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private int _timeSpan;

    public AnotherScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer = new Timer(TimerTick,null,TimeSpan.Zero,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
        MouseEnter += (s, e) => _timeSpan = 0;
    }

    private void TimerTick(object obj)
    {

        _timeSpan += 1;

        if (_timeSpan > 120)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/LoginScreen.xaml", UriKind.Relative)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Mobile (i.e. *not* Windows Phone) take a look at [this blog entry](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/05/19/DetectingApplicationIdle.aspx).